# Solve for the positions of all six roots PYTHON

Tags: python-2.7, numerical-methods, polynomial-math, newtons-method

I'm using Newton's method, so I want to find the positions of all six roots of the sixth-order polynomial, basically the points where the function is zero.

I found the rough values on my graph with this code below but want to output those positions of all six roots. I'm thinking of using x as an array to input the values in to find those positions but not sure. I'm using 1.0 for now to locate the rough values. Any suggestions from here??

```
def P(x):
        return 924*x**6 - 2772*x**5 + 3150*x**4 - 1680*x**3 + 420*x**2 - 42*x + 1
def dPdx(x):
        return 5544*x**5 - 13860*x**4 + 12600*x**3 - 5040*x**2 + 840*x - 42

accuracy = 1**-10
x = 1.0                                       
xlast = float("inf")

while np.abs(x - xlast) > accuracy:
        xlast = x
        x = xlast - P(xlast)/dPdx(xlast)
print(x)

p_points = []
x_points = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_points = np.zeros(len(x_points))
for i in range(len(x_points)):
        y_points[i] = P(x_points[i])
p_points.append(P(x_points))


plt.plot(x_points,y_points)
plt.savefig("roots.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: How about [`numpy.roots`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way is to use deflation to factor out the already found roots. If you want to avoid manipulations of the coefficient array, then you have to divide the roots out.

Having found z[1],...,z[k] as root approximations, form

```
g(x)=(x-z[1])*(x-z[2])*...*(x-z[k])
```

and apply Newtons method to `h(x)=f(x)/g(x)` with `h'(x)=f'/g-fg'/g^2`. In the Newton iteration this gives

```
xnext = x - f(x)/( f'(x) - f(x)*g'(x)/g(x) )
```

Fortunately the quotient `g'/g` has a simple form

```
g'(x)/g(x) = 1/(x-z[1])+1/(x-z[2])+...+1/(x-z[k])
```

So with a slight modification to the Newton step you can avoid finding the same root over again.

---

This all still keeps the iteration real. To get at the complex root, use a complex number to start the iteration.

---

Proof of concept, adding `eps=1e-8j` to `g'(x)/g(x)` allows the iteration to go complex without preventing real values. Solves the equivalent problem `0=exp(-eps*x)*f(x)/g(x)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def P(x):
        return 924*x**6 - 2772*x**5 + 3150*x**4 - 1680*x**3 + 420*x**2 - 42*x + 1
def dPdx(x):
        return 5544*x**5 - 13860*x**4 + 12600*x**3 - 5040*x**2 + 840*x - 42



accuracy = 1e-10

roots = []
for k in range(6):
    x = 1.0                                       
    xlast = float("inf")

    x_points = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 200)
    y_points = P(x_points)
    for rt in roots:
        y_points /= (x_points - rt)
    y_points = np.array([ max(-1.0,min(1.0,np.real(y))) for y in y_points ])

    plt.plot(x_points,y_points,x_points,0*y_points)
    plt.show()
    while np.abs(x - xlast) > accuracy:
        xlast = x
        corr = 1e-8j
        for rt in roots:
            corr += 1/(xlast-rt)
        Px = P(xlast)
        dPx = dPdx(xlast)
        x = xlast - Px/(dPx - Px*corr)
    print(x)
    roots.append(x)
```